# julia interpolation of own type with string()

Tags: julia

I'm quite new to Julia and I'm looking into porting some Python code to Julia.  This code uses __repr__() overloading to display cutsom types.  I understand that Julia provides the *string*() method for this functionality.  But I can't figure it out.

```
julia> type Thomas
         t::Integer
       end 
julia> function Base.string(t::Thomas)
         "---> $(t.t) <---"
       end
julia> r = Thomas(8);
```

With these definitions I expected my *string(::Thomas)* function to be called whenever a value of type *Thomas* needed to be converted to a string. In one case, it works as expected:

```
julia> println("$r")
---> 8 <---
```

But, for the most cases it does not:

```
julia> println(r)
Thomas(8)

julia> println(" $r")
 Thomas(8)

julia> println("r = $r")
r = Thomas(8)

julia> repr(r)
"Thomas(8)"
```

What did I get wrong ? Is there some other function I should define for my new custom type ?

I am running Julia 0.4.0-dev. (the code above was pasted from the REPL of Version 0.4.0-dev+3607 (2015-02-26 07:41 UTC), Commit bef6bf3*, x86_64-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 5):

At the moment just overriding `Base.show` should be enough, as follows.

```
type Thomas
    t::Int   # note Int not Integer
end

Base.show(io::IO, x::Thomas) = print(io, "Thomas with $(x.t)")
```

Note that in the definition of the type, you should use the concrete type `Int` (equivalent to `Int64` or `Int32`, depending on your machine's word size), not the abstract type `Integer`, which will lead to bad performance.

The situation with `Base.show`, `Base.print` etc. is indeed confusing at the moment, but with some recent work (look up `IOContext`) should get simplified and clarified soon.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override two versions of Base.print actually to get a consistent behavior of string interpolation:

```
Base.print(io::IOBuffer, t::Thomas) = Base.print(io, "---> $(t.t) <---")
Base.print(t::Thomas) = Base.print("---> $(t.t) <---")
```

Then you'll have:

```
print(t)
string(t)
string(t, t, ...)
"$t"
"t = $t"
"$t $t $t"
```

and co.

Comment: `print` will delegate to `show`, so it's better to override `Base.show` as in David Sanders' solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to override the `show` method as well.

```
Base.show(io::IO, x::Thomas) = show(io, string(x))
```

Comment: Thanks Vincent. There seems to be several functions: `show()`, `print()`, `display()` etc. What's the relation ? And where should these be used.  Should some of them produce parsable output ?  I have not found any _really_ useful information on this topic in the (otherwise very good) Julia language documentation. Any pointers appreciated!